# Work on QGIS on both Windows and Mac [UNAVAILABLE LAYER]

Tags: qgis

I'm very new to QGIS, but I can't seem to figure this one out no matter what I try.

The problem: I would like to switch between OS X and Windows working on a project. Every time I open it on OS X, however, I get the "handle unavailable layers"-dialog box.

I've tried exporting, saving in just about every way I know how, tried every solution SE and Google has given me, to no avail.

I'm sure there is an easy way of doing something as basic as this, but I have no idea how.

The project is a lot of polygons on top of a map. I've added a PDF showing a section of it in the Google Drive folder.

Google Drive folder with .qlm and .qgz file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/182xCmHLe0n3qmn-iopcDHwesS3OaiFpU?usp=sharing

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: QGIS project files don't actually contain any geo data, only paths which point to the data sources. I'm not really expert in this area, but I think you could theoretically have all your necessary data files and the project file in the same directory, then share that. If you save your project file as .qgs instead of .qgz you can open it in a text editor and manually change the paths if necessary. I haven't tried it myself and I'm not sure if it works across different OS's, but the QPackage plugin might also work  https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QPackage/

Comment: Also see the following thread and the marked duplicate:   https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173398/qgis-how-do-i-share-a-project